# ASP.net Repeater with differing content

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, video, repeater

I want to create some sort of website that lets you consume media (mainly Pictures and Videos). A user may upload media and this media is displayed alongside all other media uploaded by various users.

For that, I use a standard `Repeater`:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="elementRepeater">
</asp:Repeater>
```

There are 2 types of media elements available for me: Pictures and Videos.

As an example:
While scrolling, there are 2 pictures, followed by 5 videos, followed by 1 picture, followed by 2 videos, etc.

I thought about making a custom `MediaElement` that has both `Image` and `Video`(Microsoft.Web.Helpers.Video), but I can't seem to get it to work (since `Video` can't be used as a Property).

What would be the best way to approach this?

Comment: Your question is too vague at the moment. What is your problem? How to show a video or an image on the page? Or how to have a common interface to use as item in repeater? Or something else?

Comment: Sorry, it's difficult to explain for me. 'common interface to use as item' is probably what I'm looking for.

Comment: Don't have idea about common interface but you could add both the controls in visible false mode  in template field and onRowDataBound check for what type of file is it then make visible to true for that control.